# illegal hardware instruction solana-test-validator

Tags: solana-test-validator

When running `solana-test-validator` on terminal I got this error.

```
shivangrawat@shivangs-MacBook-Air solana % solana-test-validator
--faucet-sol argument ignored, ledger already exists
Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
⠓ Initializing
Waiting for fees to stabilize 1...
Identity: DVQ4DkbQg7MTtRbEMV9zg7Qa8YZaj3xxom4Nrj6tUasW
Genesis Hash: CywfxFRnnNVmUzsK8iV92tnrv5g3jcYj3KgXhSxpKegz
Version: 1.16.12
Shred Version: 36335
Gossip Address: 127.0.0.1:1024
TPU Address: 127.0.0.1:1027
JSON RPC URL: http://127.0.0.1:8899
WebSocket PubSub URL: ws://127.0.0.1:8900
⠁ 00:00:02 | Processed Slot: 522 | Confirmed Slot: 501 | Finalized Slot: 522 | Fulzsh: illegal hardware instruction  solana-test-validator
```

Comment: Looks like you're using a mac. What is the output of this command in the terminal: `file \`which solana-test-validator\` `?

Comment: /Users/shivangrawat/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/solana-test-validator

Comment: Don't you get something after the path? This is what I get for example: `Users/.../solana-test-validator: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64`

Comment: no, I am not getting anything after the path.

Comment: This command should give you the architecture of your solana validator: `lipo -archs /Users/shivangrawat/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/solana-test-validator`. If you are running an M1 mac, this should be `arm64`. Make sure the architecture returned matches your laptop's architecture and if not reinstall Solana Tool Suite with the correct architecture for your machine.

Comment: architecture is `x86_64`

Comment: `x86_64` is the architecture of  the app or your laptop's? As I mentioned earlier, make sure they match. I suspect your laptop is M1/arm and your solana install is x86_64 and that's why you're getting the error.